# Selenium infinite srolling and finding end loop

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrappe Magic Eden, specifically the page Collections where I want to get all the collections that exist in the page. I think I'm halfway but I can't figure out the two questions below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "https://magiceden.io/collections"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("../chromedriver/chromedriver")
# driver = webdriver.Chrome("../chromedriver/chromedriver",chrome_options=chrome_op tions)
driver.get(url)

## There is a catch with the site, it loads more data when you scroll down so I need to add this function part to scroll until the end

while driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div'):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    Divs=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div').text
    if 'End of Results' in Divs:
        print('end')
        break
    else:
        continue

"""
Q1 : I need to find a way to break out the while loop. I don't seem to find a pattern in the end of the page
"""

"""
Q2 : How do I get after loading the page, all of the href and the names of each project ?
"""
```

Comment: webpage is having infinite scrolling, in which condition do you want to break out?

Comment: There a finite number of projects. If you run my lines of code and check the page, you will see that you go to the end of the page however the loop is still going on because I don't know how to find a good pattern to break it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way around the probelem. My solution has two important pieces :

1. Using time sleep to wait for the page to load up
2. Choosing when to stop scrolling based on the height of the content

I hope it helps other people. Thank you all for your contribution.

```
def getCollectionUrl(sleepSec:int):
    """
    
    """
    url = "https://magiceden.io/collections"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("../chromedriver/chromedriver")
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(sleepSec)
    prev_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
    ### This is the part that you really need         
    while True:
        driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);')
        time.sleep(sleepSec)
        new_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
        if new_height == prev_height:
            break
        prev_height = new_height


    locContent = driver.page_source.split("p-0 text-center card collection-card me")
    locListUrl = []
    for c_ in locContent[1:]:
        locListUrl.append("https://magiceden.io"+c_.split('href="')[1].split('"><div class=')[0])
    driver.quit()
    return locListUrl
```

Comment: thanks dude, this is really helpful. I had the same problem in the same site hahaha

Answer (score 0):

If the page has an ending and loads all at once instead of using a while loop and scrolling down the page I would just use a

```
Divs=driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('div').text
```

vs

```
Divs=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div').text
```

the difference is elements will find all the elements on the page and return it as a list. element on the other hand will just return the first. This should solve your issue with not knowing when to stop because it will grab every element you want. I will say if you are trying to target a specific type of element I would use something more precise like

```
Divs=driver.find_elements_by_class("classname").text
```

This way you have all the elements you want and not every div on the page.
Finally, just use something like

```
for element in list:
    element.getAttribute("href");
```

This will get you what you want.

Comment: thank you for your reponse however find_elements_by_class doesn't exist, do you mean find_element_by_class_name ? If that's what you mean, I tried with this driver.find_element_by_class_name("p-0 text-center card collection-card me") however I get an error => driver.find_element_by_class_name("p-0 text-center card collection-card me")

Comment: I'm sorry I did mean to put "find_elements_by_class_name", not "find_elements_by_class" I think the issue now is that find_elements_by_class_name can only accept one class name. such as driver.find_element_by_class_name("p-0") you are currently giving it 4 different class names I believe. If one of those is unique to the element you are looking for use that. If not I would find the elements through its xpath.